# MultipleObjectsReturned- get() returned more than one mPurchase -- it returned 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am beginner to django. While trying to save mPurchase form I am getting MultipleObjectReturned error. I am trying to get data from form using POST request. Every time I submit the form I am getting an error.

views.py

```
def milkPurchase(request):
title='Buy Milk'
milk = mPurchase.objects.all()

if request.method=='POST':
    form=mPurchaseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        m = get_object_or_404(mPurchase)
        m.mPurchase_date=timezone.now()
        m.save()
        return redirect('milk-purchase')

else:
    form=mPurchaseForm()


context = {
    'title': title,
    'form': form,
    'milk':milk

}
return render(request,'dairyapp/milk-purchase.html',context)
```

forms.py

```
class mPurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
    This form is for milk purchase
"""

seller=forms.CharField(
   label='Seller Name',
    max_length=50,
)

mPurchase_product=forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=MILK_CHOICES,
    label='Milk Type',
    initial='',
    widget=forms.Select(),
    required=True
)

mPurchase_qty=forms.FloatField(
    label='Qty'
)

mPurchase_rate=forms.FloatField(
    label='Rate'
)

class Meta:
    model=mPurchase
    fields=('seller','mPurchase_product','mPurchase_qty','mPurchase_rate',)
```

here is my 
models.py

```
class mPurchase(models.Model):
mPurchase_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
seller=models.CharField(max_length=50)
mPurchase_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
mPurchase_product=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=MILK_CHOICES)
mPurchase_qty=models.FloatField()
mPurchase_rate=models.FloatField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.seller
```

Can you please help me get through this? I have tried using

```
mPurchase.objects.filter()
```

Also, tried to catch exception using ObjectDoesNotExist and MultipleObjectReturned

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, 
MultipleObjectsReturned
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change in here:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    form=mPurchaseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        m = form.save(commit=False)  # <--- Here
        m.mPurchase_date=timezone.now()
        m.save()
```